# Compile and run Spring project with maven

Tags: spring, maven

I saw a lot of spring projects based on maven pom.xml build file. And there was one strange thing: project built without public static void main() method. 
For example: https://github.com/geowarin/spring-mvc-security. 
In usual examples form spring.io there are classes with @SpringBootApplication annotations and SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); in main functions. So, how maven builds applications without this class and how to do it right way in terminal?

Comment: spring boot application and  regular spring mvc application  work in different ways. the git hub link you specified is a regular spring mvc application. It won't have any main method. Applications with main and with annotations as `SpringBootApplication` are spring boot applications, which are totally different in terms of packaging , building and starting the application

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do, are you just curious why Spring MVC Security doesn't need a main method or are you wondering how to use Spring MVC Security in your project?

Comment: "why Spring MVC Security doesn't need a main method?" and how to run it without this method? (in all readme files I found "mvn clean install", and after that nothing's happened)

Answer (score -1):

Go to home directory of the project in the Terminal. Type below command.

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

**Output for my project:**

[image]